# I am not able to close the modal window inside DrawerLayoutAndroid because of radio_props

Tags: react-native

I have a modal window inside DrawerLayoutAndroid.
I am able to open it, but not able to close the same.

Reason : because of radio_props

Please help me out.

---

Code :

```
var radio_props = [
  { label: 'Top-Up', value: 'T', },
  { label: 'Recharge', value: 'R' },
  { label: 'Add-on', value: 'A' },
];
<DrawerLayoutAndroid>
.
.
<Modal>
.
.
.
</Modal>
.
.
.
<View style={styles.selradio}>
              <RadioForm
               // radio_props={radio_props}
                initial={0}
                onPress={(value) => { this.setState({ RTAType: value }) }}
                formHorizontal={true}
                buttonColor={'#757575'}
                buttonSize={10}
                buttonOuterSize={20}
                labelStyle={{ marginRight: 15, }}
              />
            </View>
.
.
</DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```

While I am trying to close the Modal by clicking in Hide Modal - APK is getting stuck and it is not responding.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how everything is being called because of how you pasted your code into your question, but to me it seems like it could be an issue with you setting the modalVisible state as "visible" instead of true.

Comment: This issue is because of radio_props. Please suggest

Comment: If I comment 

               // radio_props={radio_props}

Code works. But without radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying with "react-native-simple-radio-button" this module is having some issue while re-rendering radio buttons after closing the modal window.

Instead of this I have used "react-native-paper" and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

HideModal are not a toggle for Modal, why dont you set modalVisible to false instead of reversing the modalVisible.

Comment: This issue is because of radio_props. Please suggest